# Variable takes negative value while it is restricted to be nonnegative

Tags: python, pulp

I am programming a vehicle routing problem in Python with PuLP. I got all my code in it, but for some reason I get a negative value for one of my decision variables, even though I restricted all of them to be nonnegative.

My code is as follows (Traveltimes is a two dimensional np array, with travel times between each pair of customers (i,j), where c(i,j) = c(j,i) and c(i,i) = 0.):

My code:

```
numVehicles = 2
numCustomers = 2


prob = LpProblem("DSP", LpMinimize)
var = [[[0 for k in range(numVehicles)] for j in range(numCustomers+1)] for i in range(numCustomers+1)]
for i in range(numCustomers+1):
    for j in range(numCustomers+1):
        for k in range(numVehicles):
            var[i][j][k] = LpVariable("x"+str(i)+","+str(j)+","+str(k), 0,1, cat='Binary')

# ADD OBJECTIVE
obj = ""
for i in range(numCustomers+1):
    for j in range(numCustomers+1):
        for k in range(numVehicles):
            obj += traveltimes[i][j]*var[i][j][k]
prob += obj

# ADD CONSTRAINTS

# All customers visited
for j in range(numCustomers+1):
    for k in range(numVehicles):
        nr = ""
        for i in range(numCustomers+1):
            nr += var[i][j][k] 
        prob += nr == 1

# Enter each customer exactly once
for i in range(numCustomers+1):
    nr = ""
    for k in range(numVehicles):
        for j in range(1, numCustomers+1):
            nr += var[i][j][k]
    prob += nr == 1

# Leave each customer exactly once
for j in range(numCustomers+1):
    nr = ""
    for k in range(numVehicles):
        for i in range(1, numCustomers+1):
            nr += var[i][j][k]
    prob += nr == 1

# Per vehicle only one customer can be visited as first
nrFirst = ""
for k in range(numVehicles):
    for j in range(numCustomers+1):
        nrFirst += var[0][j][k]
    prob += nrFirst <= 1

# Max num vehicles
nrOut = ""
for k in range(numVehicles):
    for j in range(numCustomers+1):
        nrOut += var[0][j][k]
prob += nrOut <= numVehicles

# Restrict x(0,j,k) to be nonpositive
for j in range(numCustomers+1):
    for k in range(numVehicles):
        prob += var[0][j][k] >= 0



print(prob)

# Solve LP
prob.solve()
for v in prob.variables(): 
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
print("objective=", value(prob.objective))
```

The first output is the formulation printed

```
MINIMIZE
1.731*x0,1,0 + 1.731*x0,1,1 + 2.983*x0,2,0 + 2.983*x0,2,1 + 1.731*x1,0,0 + 1.731*x1,0,1 + 9.375*x1,2,0 + 9.375*x1,2,1 + 2.983*x2,0,0 + 2.983*x2,0,1 + 9.375*x2,1,0 + 9.375*x2,1,1 + 0.0
SUBJECT TO
_C1: x0,0,0 + x1,0,0 + x2,0,0 = 1

_C2: x0,0,1 + x1,0,1 + x2,0,1 = 1

_C3: x0,1,0 + x1,1,0 + x2,1,0 = 1

_C4: x0,1,1 + x1,1,1 + x2,1,1 = 1

_C5: x0,2,0 + x1,2,0 + x2,2,0 = 1

_C6: x0,2,1 + x1,2,1 + x2,2,1 = 1

_C7: x0,1,0 + x0,1,1 + x0,2,0 + x0,2,1 <= 1

_C8: x1,1,0 + x1,1,1 + x1,2,0 + x1,2,1 <= 1

_C9: x2,1,0 + x2,1,1 + x2,2,0 + x2,2,1 <= 1

_C10: x0,0,0 + x0,1,0 + x0,2,0 <= 1

_C11: x0,0,0 + x0,0,1 + x0,1,0 + x0,1,1 + x0,2,0 + x0,2,1 <= 1

VARIABLES
0 <= x0,0,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x0,0,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x0,1,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x0,1,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x0,2,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x0,2,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x1,0,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x1,0,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x1,1,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x1,1,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x1,2,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x1,2,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x2,0,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x2,0,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x2,1,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x2,1,1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x2,2,0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x2,2,1 <= 1 Integer
```

It can clearly be observed that all variables are restricted to be an integer between 0 and 1 (thus binary). However, for some reason, I do get negative values for some variable(s), as can be seen below

```
x0,0,0 = 0.0
x0,0,1 = -1.0
x0,1,0 = 0.0
x0,1,1 = 1.0
x0,2,0 = 0.0
x0,2,1 = 1.0
x1,0,0 = 1.0
x1,0,1 = 1.0
x1,1,0 = 1.0
x1,1,1 = 0.0
x1,2,0 = 0.0
x1,2,1 = 0.0
x2,0,0 = 0.0
x2,0,1 = 1.0
x2,1,0 = 0.0
x2,1,1 = 0.0
x2,2,0 = 1.0
x2,2,1 = 0.0
objective= 11.159
```

Really looking forward to any suggestions on how to solve this problem, since I clearly do not want negative values!

Comment: I don't want to be an asshole, actually I am willing to help, but there is too much code to read, too much output etc. Simplify it so that we can, at a glance check the errors etc.
I get a negative value for one of my decision variables (WHICH, WHERE WHERE DO YOU FORCE IT TO BE POSITIVE??)

Comment: @E.Serra What you want to ask for is a [mcve]. Try writing `[mcve]` in your comment.

Comment: @E.Serra  I just added the output to show that I programmed it as I wanted, namely with the restriction that all variables are either 0 or 1. However, as shown in the last screen, x0,2,1 is set to -2 in the solution, which should not be possible?

Comment: if you want help, as previously stated, you'll need to provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problem is probably infeasible

Answer (score 1):

As a few others have suggested you should write a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That said, if you are getting constraints violated, and you are sure you've implemented them correctly, I reckon you have an infeasible problem (i.e. if you looked at your constraints carefully you would find there is a combination which makes solving impossible).

To check this add:

`print (("Status:"), LpStatus[prob.status])`

Just after you do `prob.solve()`. I reckon you'll find it's infeasible.

Comment: Yup problem is infeasible please check the status

Answer (score -1):

```
prob += nr == 1
```

"+=" is for assignment

"==" is checking for equivalence, and belongs in an "if" statement or a "while".

For instance:

```
if prob + nr == 1: #execute what follows if prob + nr is equal to 1
```

Comment: You can see that it resulted in the desired constraints in the second code screen (C1-C20)